# How to get enumeration inside main enumeration of the sections?

Tags: sectioning

I'm writing a thesis proposal, and I want to show the structure of my final report. I mean the structure of another report in my current report. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{TITLE}
\section{TITLE}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\section{TITLE}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsubsection{Title}
%Here the numbered structure of my final report, something like this, like table of contents of another report, not this, without page numbers, only text:
1. Title\\
2. Title\\
2.1 Subtitle\\
2.1.1 Title\\
3. Title
% Whole structure in this subsubsection.
\subsubsection{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\section{TITLE}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsubsection{Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tableofcontents` will show the sectioning hierarchy.

Comment: @mozartstraße I want to show the structure of another report in the current report.

Comment: Should the extra ToC also have the same formatting as a regular ToC? In particular, should it contain the page numbers of the original document?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The same text format, without page numbers.

Comment: And the other document was build using the `article` document class?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The other document doesn't exist yet, I'm proposing the structure of my thesis report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, you can simply use an `enumerate` environment with some adjustments to the labels. However, to facilitate the job, I would suggest you the [`easylist`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easylist) package; in the following example I chose the `articletoc` style for the list so as to simulate a real ToC, but you can choose another style (refer to the package documentation for further details):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\subsubsection{Test Subsection One One One}
\subsection{Proposed structure for the final report}
\begin{easylist}[articletoc]
\noindent& Introduction
& First Interesting Section
&& A not so Interesting Subsection
&& Another not so Interesting Subsection
& Another Interesting Section
&& A Really Interesting Subsection
&& Another Really Interesting Subsection
& Conclusions
\end{easylist}
\section{Test Section Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]